# Add multiple files to output for extra compiler Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake

I am in trouble with adding multiple files to output for Qt extra compiler.

Here's how my extra compiler looks like:

```
 new_target.input = $${INPUT_HEADERS}
 new_target.output  = $${OUTPUT_FILES}
 new_target.commands = python $${SCRIPT_NAME}.py $${CONFIG_FILE} --generate
 new_target.CONFIG += target_predeps
 new_target.variable_out = SOURCES
 new_target.dependency_type = TYPE_C
 QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += new_target
```

Everything works fine until `$${OUTPUT_FILES}` does not contain multiple files.(*for example:* `OUTPUT_FILES=first.cpp second.cpp third.cpp` )

As a result qmake recognizes only first one mentioned.

Is it possible to pass multiple files to .output field?

I'm using *Qt 4.8.6*

Comment: It's really simple: one output per target. If you need 3 outputs, you need 3 targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers) say:

> `output` - The filename that is created from the custom compiler.

Output should be one single file, not multiple. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may need to create a separate compiler target for each output file, or do in a loop using [`for(iterate, list)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#for-iterate-list):

```
OUTPUT_TARGETS=first second third
for(_TARGET, OUTPUT_TARGETS) {
    eval($${_TARGET}.input = INPUT_HEADERS)
    eval($${_TARGET}.output = $${_TARGET}.cpp)
    ...

    QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += $${_TARGET}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was typo here, but in code everything as you wrote.

Comment: Where `INPUT_HEADERS` and `OUTPUT_FILES` coming from? Try to omit `$$` for them as well.

Comment: `INPUT_HEADERS` and `OUTPUT_FILES` are being formed a bit earlier in the same `.pri` file, I guarantee, that they are formed right.

Comment: Actually, as I told, the problem is that on 'make' files `second.cpp` and `third.cpp` are being ignored by compiler. That is the problem, everything else works fine. I can't get why these two files gone

Comment: Another clarification to address the main problem. `.output` cannot be multiple files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been thinking about this kind of solution. Unfortunately I'll be able to check this only next week, but for know it will be the answer. Thanks again!)